# 3x3 Matrix rank variable

Tags: linear-algebra

For any real number $t$, let
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&t\\1&t&1\\t&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$

For which values of $t$ do we have $\text{rank}\left(A\right) = 1$? For which values of $t$ do we have $\text{rank}\left(A\right) = 2$? Justify
your answer.

Not sure how to approach this problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Clearly $t=1$...gives rank=1

Comment: @Surb what for  $t=-2$ , the determinant isn't zero ?

Answer (score 4):

Let us try first reduce the given matrix
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&t\\1&t&1\\t&1&1\end{bmatrix}$$
Apply $ R_2 \leftarrow R_2-R_1$ and   $ R_3 \leftarrow R_3-t*R_1$ we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&t\\0&t-1&1-t\\0&1-t&1-t^2\end{bmatrix}$$  Then apply  $ R_3 \leftarrow R_3+R_2$ we get
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&t\\0&t-1&1-t\\0&0&2-t-t^2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1&t\\0&t-1&1-t\\0&0&(-1-t)(2-t)\end{bmatrix} $$ And this final matrix is called the [Row Echelon Form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form)  of A, and they have the same rank, which is the number of the non zero rows.

1. If  $ t=1 $ , then clearly the rank is one .
2. If $t=-2$, then this last matrix become $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&-2\\0&-3&3\\0&0&0\end{bmatrix} $$ and cant be reduced more, thus the rank is equal to  two.
3. If $t \neq 1$ and  $t\neq -2$, then the rank is clearly three.